# Bulk API V2 Line Endings

Tags: rest-api, bulk

**Message State**                       **Status**

ClientInputError : LineEnding...    Failed

[image]

**I create my Job**

{{_endpoint}}/services/data/v{{version}}/jobs/ingest
{
"object" : "Account",
"contentType" : "CSV",
"operation" : "insert"
}

**Upload my data**
{{_endpoint}}/services/data/v{{version}}/jobs/ingest/{{_jobId}

FirstName,LastName,Description
Tom,Jones,Branding guru
Ian,Dury,Fuzzy logic expert

**close the job**
{{_endpoint}}/services/data/v{{version}}/jobs/ingest/{{_jobId}}

and get

Message State                       Status
ClientInputError : LineEnding...    Failed

**See**
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/api_basics/api_basics_bulk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your upload is using CRLF, but you didn't set the lineEnding setting to CRLF, so it used the default LF mode. Make sure you add the lineEnding setting as specified in the Trailhead module.

```
{{_endpoint}}/services/data/v{{version}}/jobs/ingest 

{ "object" : "Account", 
  "contentType" : "CSV", 
  "operation" : "insert", 
  "lineEnding": "CRLF" 
}
```